# Slack Integration in Python

Tags: python, django, slack, slack-api

I am trying to integrate slack in my python-django code and I was going through the documentation [this one](https://django-slack.readthedocs.io/).

I am not able to understand what is the `path/to/my_message.slack` refer to.

```
from django_slack import slack_message

slack_message('path/to/my_message.slack', {
    'foo': Foo.objects.get(pk=17),
})
```

Where path/to/my_message.slack (in your templates directory) :

```
{% extends django_slack %}

{% block text %}
Message text here: {{ foo.bar|urlize }} {{ foo.user.get_full_name|safe }}
{% endblock %}
```

Help!

Comment: You probably create a file with .slack extension (example.slack) where you can set the template tags just like the example is showing. So in slack_message you actually load the 'foo' as a object with the data from the Foo model. 

As usual, you operate with 'foo' variable in the 'my_message.slack' / 'example.slack' (however  you call it).

Comment: Got it! But no luck in sending msg. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Well, I have done it using another documentation in case any one want to refer to it : `https://howto.lintel.in/task-notification-bot-slack-django/`

Comment: This is a neat library, but sadly outdated. It used attachments instead of blocks, which are deprecated. So if you are building a new app I would not recommend using it. Instead use the official Python library from Slack: https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient

Comment: I didn't reliase it was outdated. Thanks mate for the info. I will try this as well. Just one question, what does `assert` refert to?

Comment: You mean in the examples of this library? assert checks that a condition is met and will raise an exception otherwise. In this case that the response from the Slack API returns `ok == True`.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot!